# How can I retrieve label text from ListBox in mosync?

Tags: listbox, mosync

I am using mosync 3.1.
I have created a listbox and added labels as listbox items. I want to be able to retrieve the text or name of the label that is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a "ItemSelectedListener" class and override the virual "itemSelected" method as this:

virtual void    itemSelected (ListBox *sender, Widget *selectedWidget, Widget *unselectedWidget)

and then use this ListBox method:

"void addItemSelectedListener (ItemSelectedListener *listener)"

When an item selected in ListBox, the "itemSelectd" method has been called with "selected widget". Then you can get a text:

((Label*)selectedWidget)->getText()